# Is a paraboloid a null set in R3?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Is a circular paraboloid a null set in R3? Intuitively, I think it is not because it has volume in R3. How can I formally prove it?

Comment: Do you mean the surface or do you mean the convex region having said surface as its boundary?

Comment: I mean the circular parabolid itself, without including the convex region "inside" it.

Comment: A paraboloid is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, so it is homeomorphic to  plane in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Since you say you only mean the surface, why do you think it has volume? Where do you find this volume in something infinitely thin?

Comment: Yes, you are right it does not have volume. I was mistaken. It is a null set then.